# Asymptotic Notation Properties - proof?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am trying to solve these problems. In the first property it seems it is transpose symmetry but there is difference of notation in `f(n)`.

For all positive `f(n)`, `g(n)` and `h(n)`

1. If `f(n) = O(g(n))` and `f(n) = Ω(h(n))`, then
   `g(n) + h(n) = (f(n))`.
2. If `f(n) = O(g(n))` and `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`, then we have `(f(n))3 = Θ((g(n))3)`
3. If `f(n) = O(g(n))` and `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`, then we have `(f(n))2 = (g(n))2`

Comment: There are letters missing in your equations. Please correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct this is transpose of function h(n), g(n),h(n).And all the function has same growth at all in first case.
Theta f(n)=Theta g(n)+Theta h(n)